# Icon on same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my project I'm using bootstrap. But I've got this frustrating problem where the mail icon won't go on the same line.

Currently I've got this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
      
<div class="panel panel-primary">
     <div class="panel-heading">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-10">
           <a style="color: white;" href="#">Username</a> -
           <a style="color:white;" href="#">Corporation</a> 
           <i class="material-icons">&#xE0BE;</i>
         </div>

         <div class="col-md-2">
           <p>time</p>
         </div>
       </div>

     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
       <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
         <div class="col-md-12 panel-body-margin-bottom">
           <h3>subject</h3>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row trix-content">
         <div class="col-md-12 panel-body-margin-top">
           <p>Message</p>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Any idea how I could fix this (without `margin-top`)

Comment: Try putting a border around the icon to visually see its bounds. There may be empty space underneath it. If not, try `margin-bottom=0` and see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks significantly prettier.  The vertical-align will force it to center it on the line properly.  But then I noticed it was still just a little off, so I used margin-top:-3px to make it look just a bit better.

```
<i class="material-icons" style="margin-top:-3px;vertical-align:middle;">&#xE0BE;</i>
```

Full code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
      
<div class="panel panel-primary">
     <div class="panel-heading">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-10">
           <a style="color: white;" href="#">Username</a> -
           <a style="color:white;" href="#">Corporation</a> 
           <i class="material-icons" style="margin-top:-3px;vertical-align:middle;">&#xE0BE;</i>
         </div>

         <div class="col-md-2">
           <p>time</p>
         </div>
       </div>

     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
       <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
         <div class="col-md-12 panel-body-margin-bottom">
           <h3>subject</h3>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row trix-content">
         <div class="col-md-12 panel-body-margin-top">
           <p>Message</p>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
      
<div class="panel panel-primary">
     <div class="panel-heading">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-10" >
           <span style="vertical-align:super;"><a style="color: white;" href="#">Username</a> -
           <a style="color:white;" href="#">Corporation</a> </span>
           <span><i class="material-icons" style="    font-size: 19px;">&#xE0BE;</i></span>
           
         </div>

         <div class="col-md-2">
           time
         </div>
       </div>

     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
       <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
         <div class="col-md-12 panel-body-margin-bottom">
           <h3>subject</h3>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row trix-content">
         <div class="col-md-12 panel-body-margin-top">
           <p>Message</p>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```